# how to remove certain substring from string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring

```
a="<img src="hug.jpg/> India is a good country <img src="hug.jpg/> America is also good country "
```

So I want to here is `<img/>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [104]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [105]: a="<img src=\"hug.jpg\"/> India is a good country <img src=\"hug.jpg\"/> America is also good country"

In [287]: soup = BeautifulSoup(a,"html.parser")

In [288]: soup.text
Out[288]: ' India is a good country  America is also good country'

In [289]: soup.text.strip()
Out[289]: 'India is a good country  America is also good country'
```

Comment: bro im sorry not "<img/>" tags i want a output is "India is a good country America is also good country". So i want to remove "<img/> tags from the string